# Place connected boxes on a 2D plane

Tags: algorithm

Given N rectangular boxes and M connections between them, I want to place them on a plane efficiently such that the total sum of length of all connections remains to a minimum.

The only throught process I have is to split the plane in to a grid with N or more spaces, and place those boxes with maximum number of connections as farther apart in the grid starting with diagonally opposite corner spaces.

This might not be efficient when there is one box connected to all N-1 boxes and those are the only connections. We would expect that one box in the center and all other boxes around it.

Is there a standard solution for such a problem? Can I get a pointer as to how to approach such a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a non-linear optimization problem and it can be solved, for instance, using simulated annealing or general objective function minimization such as gradient descent methods.

Given any layout of your boxes, let L denote the sum of the lengths of all connections given that layout. You want to minimize L. A simple simulated annealing scheme works like this:

```
layout = random_layout()
t = 1.0
While(true)
  L = sum_of_lengths(layout)
  layout' = move_one_box(layout)
  L' = sum_of_lengths(layout)
  if (L' < L  or  random(0..1) < t)
    layout = layout'
  t = t * 0.999
```

Initially, the algorithm just moves boxes randomly around, but when t decreases, the algorithm gradually changes to a greedy optimizer. You can run multiple runs of the algorithm and pick the best result. This is a simulated annealing scheme.